# Зависимость padding-top от высоты псевдоэлемента

Tags: css, css3, scss

На странице есть блок:

```
.steps_item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: (100%/3); 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 292px;
    transition: width .3s linear;
    @include adaptive(900px, 900px) {
        width: (100%/2);
    }
    @include adaptive(mobile) {
        width: (100%);
    }
}
```

В нем абсолютно позиционированный псевдо-элемент:

```
.steps_item::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 81.21%;
    height: 0; // эта и следующая строчка используются для зависимости 
    padding-bottom: 88.4848%; // высоты от ширины
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Сейчас при ресайзе окна браузера псевдоэлемент ведет себя так, как нужно, его размеры пропорционально изменяются в зависимости от ширины его родителя.
Но есть одна проблема: в данном коде `padding-top` у родителя задан жестко в пикселях, необходим он для того, что бы сдвинуть остальной контент ниже псевдо-элемента + отступ от него.
Так вот, как сделать этот самый `padding` зависящий от динамической высоты псевдо-элемента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамическая высота псевдоэлемента зависит от его ширины, а та, в свою очередь, от ширины элемента, которая зависит от ширины экрана.

При выбранном разрешении экрана, когда 292px смотрятся наилучшим образом, вычислите, сколько % от ширины экрана составляют 292px (предположим, 20%) и замените

```
padding-top: 20vw;
```

Comment: обернул блок в еще один див, он уже считает ширину от экрана, а сам item и все что в нем уже от него.... не самый лучший подход, но пойдет....  попробую и Ваш совет, но позже... Спасибо.

Comment: Я потому сразу и советовал в vw. Уверен был, что основной блок еще многократно во что-то обернут.